# Sentence with dass with three Verbs (One modal and two connected with zu)

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunction

I would like to say in german:
"I have to try to reach this goal."

How is it gonna be? 
"Ich muss versuchen, diesen Ziel zu erreichen."?

What if I want to say:
"I didn't know, that I have to try to reach this goal."

Would it be? 
"Ich habe nicht gewusst, dass ich versuchen muss, diesen Ziel zu erreichen."?

Comment: "Ich wußte nicht, daß ich diesen Ziel zu erreichen versuchen muß." Aber Muttersprächler können irgenwie immer lösen, die Zahl der Verbe am Ende unten 2 minimieren :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your suggestions are correct, apart from *dieses Ziel* instead of *diesen Ziel*.
The only thing that counts are conjugated verbs (infinities do not matter), those must be alone in their part of the sentence. I highlight them in bold:

> Ich **muss** versuchen, dieses Ziel zu erreichen.
>
> Ich habe nicht **gewusst**, dass ich versuchen **muss**, dieses Ziel zu erreichen.

Note that there is no sub-sentence with more than one conjugated verb, as every sub-sentence is separated from the others by a comma.

Also, the comma before the infinitve group is optional:

> Ich **muss** versuchen dieses Ziel zu erreichen.
>
> Ich habe nicht **gewusst**, dass ich versuchen **muss** dieses Ziel zu erreichen.